# The super Grassmannian $G_{2|2}(4|4)$

Tags: mathematical-physics, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

In [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611075), the super Grassmannian $G_{2|2}(4|4)$ is defined by (12)--(18).

An element of $G_{2|2}(4|4)$ can be written as a $(2 | 2) \times (4 | 4)$ matrix of full rank modulo the left action by an invertible $(2 | 2) \times (2 | 2)$ matrix. The definition of full rank for supermatrices is there is an invertible $(2 | 2) \times (2 | 2)$ submatrix.

**My questions are:**

1. Can we write an element in $G_{2|2}(4|4)$ as follows?
   \begin{align}
   \left( \begin{array}{c c c c | c c c c} x_{11} & x_{12} &  x_{13} & x_{14} & x_{15} &  x_{16} & x_{17} & x_{18} \\  x_{21} & x_{22} &  x_{23} & x_{24} & x_{25} &  x_{26} & x_{27} & x_{28} \\ \hline x_{31} & x_{32} &  x_{33} & x_{34} & x_{35} &  x_{36} & x_{37} & x_{38} \\ x_{41} & x_{42} &  x_{43} & x_{44} & x_{45} &  x_{46} & x_{47} & x_{48} \end{array} \right)
   \end{align}
2. What are the differences between the Grassmannian $G(4,8)$ and super Grassmannian $G_{2|2}(4|4)$? I think that one difference is that the entries of matrices in $G_{2|2}(4|4)$ are even or odd and the entries of matrices in $G(4,8)$ are all even.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): It seems you basically answered your own questions.